# ssis import file with dynamic name

Tags: dynamic, import, ssis

I tried to create a SSIS package to  input excel file into database.
The excel file has dynamic name, and also i need to add filename into the database as well.

What I'm trying to do:

1. use for each file loop to set a variable called FileFound,  with the value of 
   the filename (with full path)
2. set connection for the input file with above variable
3. use data load to load the excel to db, with above connection.

I got error saying the connection is invalid.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THtMd.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zApQf.jpg)

@Admin,
I tried to upload 2 images, and I got 2 image urls but they are not working.
can you please check?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/THtMd.jpg
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zApQf.jpg

Comment: Set property for DelayValidation to true on ExcelConn

Comment: @KeithL yes it works!!! thanks you. can you please add in the answer so that i can mark as correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is step you missed when using dynamic file names in a foreach loop. You need to set delay validation property of the dynamic source (in your case the Excel Conn) to TRUE.

The package tries to validate in pre-execute phase unless you delay it.